# Jquery Ajax Load every 1 second

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I found this script in W3 school.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").load("demo_test.txt");
    });
});
</script>
```

What this script does is when ever a person click the button it will load the demo_text.txt. What I need is to make it load every 30 sec.

Help me please.

Comment: @khaled no its not. This is simpler.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `window.setInterval`:

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.setInterval(function () {
        $("#div1").load("demo_test.txt");
    }, 30000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: thank you it work!

Comment: Glad to help! If this or any answer has solved your question, please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. Doing so indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is, however, no obligation to do this. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

A ajax solution I would prefer:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var loop = setInterval(function(){
            $.ajax('demo_test.txt', {

            }).done(function (txt) {
                $("#div1").html(txt);
            });
         }, 30000);           
    });
});
```

Comment: This is incorrect. `setInterval()` takes the *timer* argument, not `$.ajax()`. Plus you failed to include the closing parenthesis for `setInterval(`

Comment: Sorry, lost the overview couse im doing it with my smartphone.